# 60 minutes, BIG DATA in marketing pruppose

Tags: osx-mavericks, hosts

I just saw a episode with 60 minutes US and there was an sequence with all the "social media" that's going on today - that they saving information about all their the users.

And then i found http://pointhope.de/tips&tricks/no_place_like_localhost.html from a users comment on 60 minutes site.

Can someone please explain this for me? or is it just bogus?

```
**My hosts file today, OSx 10.9.2 Mavericks
SPELARE-2:~ x$ cat /private/etc/hosts
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost**
```

Comment: The site looks highly suspect. No system can be totally protected from internet nasties. Implement good practice by not visiting sites like this and you will be fine. Are you really surprised social media sites save your data? If you don't like it don't go on there, otherwise you just have to accept it.

Comment: Nothing bad there. The source of the hosts file is trustworthy. AdAway for Android also uses it, among others. Still, it’s more of an ad-blocking thing, and not really about malware or the like.

Answer (score 1):

Computers don't understand domain names (e.g. superuser.com) without first resolving it into IP address.  Normally this is done through DNS lookup from DNS servers.

The `hosts` file tells the computer the IP addresses of pre-defined domain names without having to enquire DNS server.  In your link, unwanted sites are linked to the IP address 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1 is always localhost i.e. the computer you are using), so unwanted sites can never be reached (as their real IP is never resolved).